# Disable all Radcomboboxes inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radcombobox

I have several telerik radcomboboxes inside a div with various id's. I want to find all of them and disable them without using those id's like say finding the tag name using javascript.
Please help

Comment: I tried finding all input tags and then disabling them but that is just disabling the text box inside the radcombobox.

Comment: Post rendered HTML and javascript code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each RadControl renders a specific CSS class identifying the type of the control on the control container element. Additionally the JS object is an expando of the container element - `control`.

So, you can use this: `$('.common-container-class-name .RadComboBox').each(function() { this.control.disable(); });`

Comment: Thanks @simich.. finding the class name .radcombobox does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a Rad Combo Box is but it seems like different types of input / text elements so try:

```
$('.someContainerDiv input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Change input for whatever the element is, like the `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: The element is <telerik:radcombobox> it renders as <input> and <a> tag. I tried what you suggested but it didnt work.